# Iterating through a GraphML (XML) file and extracting all the values

Tags: xml, python-3.x, loops, graphml

I have an XML (actually GraphML) file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<graphml>
    <key attr.name="label" attr.type="string" id="label"/>
    <graph edgedefault="directed" id="">
        <node id="0">
            <type>p</type>
            <label>sshd(3,2)</label>
        </node>
        <node id="1">
            <type>e</type>
            <label>user(3)</label>
        </node> 
    </graph>
</graphml>
```

I want to iterate through this and extract each individual item (print it). In a normal XML file, this is reasonably straight forward, however in this case I can't seem to be able to do this. Here is the code that I am using.

```
tree = ET.parse(FILENAME)
    root=tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
        for x in child:
            NodeType =  child.find('node').find('type')
            LabelType = child.find('node').find('label')
            print(NodeType.text, LabelType.text)
```

What this gives me are the first two values repeated twice, in other words:

```
p  sshd(3,2)
p  sshd(3,2)
```

instead of:

```
p  sshd(3,2)
e  user(3)
```

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify exact path from the root to `node` elements at once :

```
for node in root.findall('graph/node'):
    print(node.find('type').text, node.find('label').text)
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/821722)</kbd>**

Comment: This works thanks!, however, it doesn't retrieve the 'id' value for each node. I should have made the question clearer. I want to get back: 
0 p  sshd(3,2)
1 e  user(3)

Comment: simply add : `node.get('id')`

Answer (score 0):

x is never used in the nested loop

```
for child in root:
    for x in child:
```